# bootstrap3-wysihtml5 insert auto image responsive class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I am using bootstrap3-wysihtml5 for my text boxes, but I want my images to have the responsive class automatically when I insert them, I have tried to insert the image without the class, then go to code mode and add the image but when going into mode seen the class is deleted. That is, it is impossible to maintain the responsive class. Is there any way to insert the images with the class? As a curious fact, the attribute alt = "" is inserted and when modifying or writing inside the attribute the description of the image in code mode, when passing to preview mode these changes if they are maintained.

This is what I have when I insert the image:

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://example/01.jpg"><br></p>
```

This is what I want:

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://example/01.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br></p>
```

I know I have to modify something inside the .js but I do not know in what part of the code I have to add the class. Here you have the complete code that I am using:

https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/blob/master/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js

Answer (score 0):

for image responsive apply these attribute to img
or create a class and add these attribute in it

max-width: 100%;
height: auto;